# Work by magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, work, magnetostatics

we all know that magnetic field doesn't work....if a current carrying element pulls a metal piece then work is done by the source or the battery not the field.....now let us assume that a bar magnet pulls another magnet / metal above ground and does a work Mgh....now do does this work?  here the source of the field is rotating electrons and we can't blame them to b doing the work ...since electrons rotates in fixed orbit with fixed energies......i dont understand what am i missing?

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/286506/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Magnets be used to pick up pieces of metal when the force from a magnetic field does no work?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67826/)

Comment: hey not duplicate okk...ijust didn't knew...n btw i saw those answer s  ...not helpful...

Comment: See magnetic energy in [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_energy)

Answer (score 0):

Try to look here. Quite lot of confusion everywhere, but with some effort I'm sure you'll get to the point. [How can Magnets be used to pick up pieces of metal when the force from a magnetic field does no work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67826/how-can-magnets-be-used-to-pick-up-pieces-of-metal-when-the-force-from-a-magneti)

Comment: If you think a question is a duplicate, then flag the question as duplicate instead of commenting. If you are not sure, you may still flag or leave a comment to the question.